# Postgres: Remove Duplicate Rows returned by ST_Dwithin query

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-dwithin

I am having trouble finding a query that returns one row for every unique vehicle crash that is within 100 feet of a select group of road features. My query currently returns a row for every collision that is within 100 feet of these roads, but because some crashes occurred within 100 feet of multiple road features, there are duplicate rows for some crashes. How can I remove these duplicates? I only one one row for each collision.

So far I have:

```
SELECT crashes.* , roads.geom, ST_Distance(crashes.geom, roads.geom)
FROM crashes, roads
WHERE ST_Dwithin(crashes.geom, roads.geom, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Properly functioning query that produces only one row for each collision within 100 feet of a potential corridor route:

```
WITH collisions AS(
    SELECT 
        crashes.case_id, 
        roads.geom, 
        ST_Distance(crashes.geom, roads.geom) d
    FROM 
        crashes, roads
    WHERE 
        ST_Dwithin(crashes.geom, roads.geom, 100)
    GROUP BY 
        crashes.case_id, d, roads.geom
)
SELECT case_id, MAX(d)
FROM crashes
GROUP BY case_id
```

Description: 
The first part of the query is a CTE, common table expression. This creates a temporary table that can be referenced and selected from in a secondary query. So the first table, created by the CTE, returns all collisions within 100ft of a potential route, but as some collisions are within 100 ft of more than one potential route feature, duplicate rows are created for these collisions.

The second Query filters these out using an aggregate expression using MAX, to only select the largest distance for each case_id (1 value, and hence 1 row for each case id). 
This effectively filters out the duplicate rows.

** `FIRST()` instead of `MAX()` also works.

Comment: It’s also possible to use SELECT DISTINCT ON (crashes.case_id) ... FROM crashes JOIN roads ON ST_Dwithin(crashes.geom, roads.geom) ORDER BY crashes.case_id, ST_Distance(crashes.geom, roads.geom)

Comment: If you don't want the road information, just compute `max(st_distance(..)) .. group by id`

Comment: FIRST() is not a built-in function, so it'll have to be added. The function definition is here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method that may be a little simpler to understand and more flexible would be to create the table, insert unique identifiers using `ST_DWithin()` and `DISTINCT` and then `UPDATE` the rest of the values where the unique id matches the source as done in the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
g_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
geom geometry,
rd_owner VARCHAR(8),
rd_name VARCHAR(71));

INSERT INTO my_table (g_id)
SELECT DISTINCT s.g_id
FROM automated.streets s, generated.sub_network sn
WHERE st_dwithin(s.geom, sn.geom, 30);

UPDATE my_table mt
SET geom = s.geom,
    rd_owner = s.rd_owner,
    rd_name = s.rd_name
FROM automated.streets s
WHERE s.g_id = mt.tdg_id;
```